# user-score ranking ,select right data structure

Tags: algorithm

I have problem to solve.

I will keep getting userid-score updating. which is an integer and another long.
I need to support two actions.

1. add userid-score, and return rank.  (based on score)
2. return user id based on rand.  (e.g.  input:3 , return 3rd highest score with id)

What data structure should I choose?
I thought about BST, it is fast for insertion. But not easy to get Kth value.

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate any tree structure so that each node stores the number of descendants below that node, updating this as you modify the tree structure. Then when you want to find the kth highest score, navigate down from the root, using the number of descendants stored beneath each node to tell you whether to branch left or right.

E.g. if the root has two children each with 8 descendants go for the one with the largest key if you want to find the 1st..8th highest ranked player.

I wrote something to support something like this for fun and I based it on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap. It is balanced with high probability, but needs far less code than AVL or red-black trees.

(Of course if you just want to retrieve the top N items in order to show a high score table, you don't need this at all, as it is relatively easy to pull of the top N items from a BST).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree), as @mcdowella said its basically any `Binary search tree` or `B tree`, that also supports 2 more operations :

`Select` : find the ith smallest element

`Rank` : find the index of the element given by corresponding value when all the elements are sorted.

These operations can be easily implemented using simple `tree traversal`.

There is also a inbuilt GNU C++ implementation of it you can read more about it here : [C++ STL: Policy based data structures.](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/11080)